# str_replace $_POST variable value in array

Tags: php, str-replace

and thank you for your time. I am currently taking an online PHP course, and am trying to figure something out that is not covered in the course.
There is a form in which errors are placed in an array if they exist according to certain parameters. Currently when the errors are displayed to the user, it shows the $_POST value, but I would like to show a custom error message. I am currently trying to use in_array and string replace, and failing. I am not getting any PHP errors. 
Anyone know how I can do this?
Here's my controller and view:

```
<?php
// add database connection script
include_once 'resource/database.php';
include_once 'resource/utilities.php';


// process the form if the reset password button is clicked
if(isset($_POST['passwordResetBtn'])) {
  // initialize an array to store any error message from the form
  $form_errors = array();

  // form validation
  $required_fields = array('email', 'new_password', 'confirm_password');

  // call the function to check empty fields and merge the return data into form_error array
  $form_errors = array_merge($form_errors, check_empty_fields($required_fields));

  // Fields that require checking for minimum length
  $fields_to_check_length = array('new_password' => 6, 'confirm_password' => 6);

  // call the function to check minimum required length and merge the return data into form_errors array
  $form_errors = array_merge($form_errors, check_min_length($fields_to_check_length));

  // email validation / merge the return data into the form_errors array
  $form_errors = array_merge($form_errors, check_email($_POST));

  // check if error array is empty, if yes process form data and insert record
  if(empty($form_errors)) {
    // collect form data and store in variables
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password1 = $_POST['new_password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['confirm_password'];



    // check if the new password and confirm password are the same
    if($password1 != $password2) {
      $result = "<p style='padding: 20px; border: 1px solid red; color: red;'>Passwords do not match, please do it over!</p>";
    } else {
      try {
        // create sql select statement to verify if email address input exists in the database
        $sqlQuery = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email";
        $statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $statement->execute(array(':email' => $email));
        // check if record exists
        if($statement->rowCount() == 1) {
          // hash the password
          $hashed_password = password_hash($password1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
          // SQL statement to update password
          $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE users SET password = :password WHERE email = :email";
          // sanitize the statement
          $statement = $db->prepare($sqlUpdate);
          // execute statement
          $statement->execute(array(':password' => $hashed_password, ':email' => $email));
          $result = "<p style='padding: 20px; border: 1px solid green; color: green;'>Password reset successfully</p>";
        } else {
          $result = "<p style='padding: 20px; border: 1px solid red; color: red;'>The email address provided does not exist in our database. Check your spelling or try another email address, por favor.</p>";
        }
      } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $result = "<p style='padding: 20px; border: 1px solid red; color: red;'>An error occurred: " . $ex->getMessage() . "</p>";
      }
    }
  } else {
    if(count($form_errors) == 1) {
      $result = "<p style='color: red;'>There was one error in the form</p><br>";
    } else {
      $result = "<p style='color: red;'>There were " . count($form_errors) . " errors in the form</p><br>";
    }
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Password Reset Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php if(isset($result)) echo $result; ?>
  <?php if(!empty($form_errors)) echo show_errors($form_errors); ?>

  <form method="post" action="">
    <table>
      <tr><td>Email:<td><input type="text" value="" name="email"></td></td></tr>
      <tr><td>New Password<td><input type="password" value="" name="new_password"></td></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Confirm Password:</td> <td><input type="password" value="" name="confirm_password"></td></tr>
      <tr><td></td><td><input style="float: right;" type="submit" name="passwordResetBtn" value="Reset Password"></td></tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <p><a href="index.php">Back</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the function from utilities.php to check minimum length of the fields:

```
function check_min_length($fields_to_check_length) {
  // initialize an array to store error messages
  $form_errors = array();
  foreach($fields_to_check_length as $name_of_field => $minimum_length_required) {
    if(strlen(trim($_POST[$name_of_field])) < $minimum_length_required) {
      $form_errors[] = $name_of_field . " is too short, must be {$minimum_length_required} characters long";
    }
  }
  return $form_errors;
}
```

Here are my lame attempts to try and find the $_POST['new_password'] value and swap it for the string "New password"

1st attempt)

```
if(isset($_POST[$name_of_field]) && $_POST[$name_of_field] == $_POST['new_password']) {
$name_of_field = str_replace($name_of_field, "New password", $_POST['new_password']);
}
```

2nd attempt)

```
if(in_array($_POST['new_password'], $form_errors)) {
  $_POST['new_password'] = str_replace($_POST['new_password'], "New Password", $form_errors);
}
```

I have tried putting my attempts just about everywhere within the main controller and the check_min_length function. I know my attempts are laughable. I am still trying to learn basic PHP and programming in general.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you need to turn display_errors in your php.ini on and the restart apache or check your error log to find the error you are getting

Comment: Thank you, Liam. My display errors were on by default in MAMP. I assume my PHP had no errors, but the code was not doing anything, since I essentially was not targeting anything. Then again, I am still new, so my confidence is very low with this reply.

Comment: If you are unsure then you can always check your error log and take a look at your last error as if you receive a blank screen chances are your errors are not displayed but can be overwritten at the top of your code by using ini_set () and overwriting the ini settings

Comment: For some reason in my PHP Info page in MAMP, it said errors were turned on, but in my ini file it said they were not on. I have been getting errors, but not the ones I am seeing in the log file you directed me to. Thank you very much for showing me to go there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$form_errors = str_replace('new_password', 'New Password', $form_errors);
```

The error message just contains the name of the input field, not the value of the input. And you need to assign the result back to the array variable, since `str_replace` doesn't modify the array in place, it returns a new array with all the replacements.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar. Works great. I really appreciate your time. I appreciate your explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should do something like this:

```
function check_min_length($fields_to_check_length) {
  // initialize an array to store error messages
  $form_errors = array();
  foreach($fields_to_check_length as $name_of_field => $minimum_length_required) {
    if(strlen(trim($_POST[$name_of_field])) < $minimum_length_required) {
      // check name of current field here:
      if ($name_of_field != 'new_password') {
        $form_errors[] = $name_of_field . " is too short, must be {$minimum_length_required} characters long";
      } else {
        $form_errors[] = "New password is too short, must be {$minimum_length_required} characters long";
      }
    }
  }
  return $form_errors;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm.